# Add tootip feature to select2 dropdown using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a dropdown feature in a field and I want to add a tooltip pop-up whenever I hover over an option, and there are multiple options. I want the tooltip to display that option content (i.e. "Hello", "Greetings", etc.). Also, when I hover over an option, it adds an additional class "select2-highlighted". How can I also compensate for this?

```
<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="width: 175px; display: block; top: 653.833px; left: 609.467px;">
    <ul class="select2-results">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class=select2-result-label">Hello</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class=select2-result-label">Greetings</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class=select2-result-label">Good-bye</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class=select2-result-label">Salutations</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class=select2-result-label">See ya!</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Below is a code snippet of an example that I've seen that I want to happen. However, I'm confused as to which class to use. This is what I've gotten so far. I put an alert in there to make sure if I'm doing it right.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.select2-results-dept-0').click(function() {
        alert("TEST TEST TEST");
    });
});
```

Below is an example that I've seen that I've been trying to implement.

```js
$('.uitip').tooltip();
```

```html
<div>
    <h4>Default behaviours</h4>
    <select>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <h4 class='uitip' title='Tests with jQuery UI Tooltips applied'>jQuery UI tooltips</h4>
    <select class='uitip' title='has tooltips'>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple class='uitip' title='has tooltips'>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".select2-result-selectable").on("mouseover", function(event){
  $(".tooltip").html(event.target.innerHTML);
  $(".tooltip").css({"display":"block", "left": (event.clientX+5)+"px", "top": (event.clientY+5)+"px"});  
});
$(".select2-result-selectable").on("mouseout", function(event){
  $(".tooltip").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
/*
Version: 3.4.5 Timestamp: Mon Nov  4 08:22:42 PST 2013
*/
.select2-container {
 margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: inherit;
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 font-size: 0.875rem;
 
 background: #fafafa url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGlkPSJMYXllcl8xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB4PSIwcHgiIHk9IjBweCIgd2lkdGg9IjE2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iM3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTYgMyIgZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ9Im5ldyAwIDAgMTYgMyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHBvbHlnb24gcG9pbnRzPSI1Ljk5MiwwIDIuOTkyLDMgLTAuMDA4LDAgIi8+PC9zdmc+DQo=") no-repeat;
 background-position-x: 100%;
 background-position-y: center;
 
}
.select2-container:hover {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 border-color: #999;
}
 
.error .select2-container {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
 
.select2-container,
.select2-drop,
.select2-search,
.select2-search input {
  /*
 Force border-box so that % widths fit the parent
 container without overlap because of margin/padding.

 More Info : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html
  */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* webkit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* firefox */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* css3 */
}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 height: 2.315rem;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
 
 white-space: nowrap;
 line-height: 1.3125rem;
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
         box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 
}
 
.select2-container.select2-drop-above .select2-choice {
 /*border-bottom-color: #aaa;*/
}
 
.select2-container.select2-allowclear .select2-choice .select2-chosen {
 margin-right: 42px;
}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen {
 margin-right: 1rem;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice abbr {
 display: none;
 width: 9px;
 height: 9px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 24px;
 top: 13px;
 
 font-size: 1px;
 text-decoration: none;
 
 border: 0;
 background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") 50% 50% no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: 0;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
 
.select2-container.select2-allowclear .select2-choice abbr {
 display: inline-block;
}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice abbr:hover {
 /*background-position: right -11px;*/
 opacity: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 
.select2-drop-mask {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 9998;
 /* styles required for IE to work */
 background-color: #fff;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
 
.select2-drop {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: -1px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 100%;
 
 background: #fafafa;
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-top: 0;
 
 outline: none;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px #999999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px #999999;
         box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px #999999;
 
/*
 padding-top: 2.315rem;
 margin-top: -2.315rem;
*/
}
 
 
.select2-drop-auto-width {
 border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
 width: auto;
}
 
.select2-drop-auto-width .select2-search {
 padding-top: 4px;
}
 
.select2-drop.select2-drop-above {
 /*margin-top: 1px;*/
 /*border-top: 1px solid #aaa;*/
 /*border-bottom: 0;*/
 
 padding-top: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: -4.630rem;
 padding-bottom: 2.315rem;
 
}
 
.select2-drop-active {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-top: none;
}
 
.select2-drop.select2-drop-above.select2-drop-active {
 border-top: 1px solid #999;
}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
 display: none;
/*    width: 18px;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;

 border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
 border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;

 background-clip: padding-box;

 background: #ccc;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ccc), color-stop(0.6, #eee));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#eeeeee', endColorstr = '#cccccc', GradientType = 0);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);
*/}
 
.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow b {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url('select2.png') no-repeat 0 1px;
}
 
.select2-search {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 26px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 
 position: relative;
 /*z-index: 10000;*/
 
 white-space: nowrap;
}
 
.select2-search input {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 min-height: 26px;
 padding: 4px 20px 4px 5px;
 margin: 0;
 
 outline: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 /*font-size: 1em;*/
 
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
         box-shadow: none !important;
 
 background: #fff url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px;
/*    background: url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px, -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.85, #fff), color-stop(0.99, #eee));
 background: url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px, -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
 background: url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px, -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
 background: url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px, linear-gradient(top, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
*/}
 
.select2-drop.select2-drop-above .select2-search input {
 margin-top: 4px;
}
 
.select2-search input.select2-active {
 background: #fff url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%;
/*    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.85, #fff), color-stop(0.99, #eee));
 background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
 background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
 background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, linear-gradient(top, #fff 85%, #eee 99%);
*/}
 
.select2-container-active .select2-choice,
.select2-container-active .select2-choices {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 outline: none;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
         box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
}
 
.select2-dropdown-open .select2-choice {
 /*border-bottom-color: transparent;*/
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 background: #fafafa;
 /*z-index: 10000;*/
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
}
 
.select2-dropdown-open.select2-drop-above .select2-choice,
.select2-dropdown-open.select2-drop-above .select2-choices {
 /*border: 1px solid #999;*/
 border-top-color: #ccc;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
 
.select2-dropdown-open .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
 background: transparent;
 border-left: none;
 filter: none;
}
.select2-dropdown-open .select2-choice .select2-arrow b {
 background-position: -18px 1px;
}
 
/* results */
.select2-results {
 max-height: 200px;
 padding: 0 0.25rem;
 margin: 0.25rem 0;
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 font-size: 0.875rem;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
 
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
 
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 20px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 40px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 60px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 80px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 100px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 110px }
.select2-results ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub ul.select2-result-sub > li .select2-result-label { padding-left: 120px }
 
.select2-results li {
 list-style: none;
 display: list-item;
 background-image: none;
}
 
.select2-results li.select2-result-with-children > .select2-result-label {
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
.select2-results .select2-result-label {
 padding: 0.25rem;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 min-height: 1em;
 
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}
 
.select2-results .select2-highlighted {
 background: #3875d7;
 color: #fff;
}
 
.select2-results li em {
 background: #feffde;
 font-style: normal;
}
 
.select2-results .select2-highlighted em {
 background: transparent;
}
 
.select2-results .select2-highlighted ul {
 background: #fff;
 color: #000;
}
 
 
.select2-results .select2-no-results,
.select2-results .select2-searching,
.select2-results .select2-selection-limit {
 background: transparent;
 display: list-item;
 padding: 0.25rem;
 color: #999;
 font-style: italic;
}
 
/*
disabled look for disabled choices in the results dropdown
*/
.select2-results .select2-disabled.select2-highlighted {
 color: #666;
 background: #eee;
 display: list-item;
 cursor: default;
}
.select2-results .select2-disabled {
  background: #eee;
  display: list-item;
  cursor: default;
}
 
.select2-results .select2-selected {
 display: none;
}
 
.select2-more-results.select2-active {
 background: #f4f4f4 url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%;
}
 
.select2-more-results {
 background: #f4f4f4;
 display: list-item;
}
 
/* disabled styles */
 
.select2-container.select2-container-disabled .select2-choice {
 background-color: #eee;
 background-image: none;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 cursor: default;
}
 
.select2-container.select2-container-disabled .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
 background-color: #eee;
 background-image: none;
 border-left: 0;
}
 
.select2-container.select2-container-disabled .select2-choice abbr {
 display: none;
}
 
 
/* multiselect */
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
 height: auto !important;
 height: 1%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 
 font-size: 0.875rem;
 cursor: text;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 background-color: #fafafa;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 
.select2-locked {
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px !important;
}
 
.select2-container-multi.select2-container-active .select2-choices {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 outline: none;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
         box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
}
 
 
.select2-container-multi.select2-container-active.select2-dropdown-open .select2-choices {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices li {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input {
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 1px 0;
 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: #666;
 outline: 0;
 border: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
 background: transparent !important;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input.select2-active {
 background: #fff url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100% !important;
}
 
.select2-default {
 color: #999 !important;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice {
 padding: .1875rem .5rem .1875rem 1.25rem;
 margin: .25rem 0 0 .25rem;
 position: relative;
 
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 color: #333;
 cursor: default;
 
 background-color: #ddd;
 
 background-clip: padding-box;
 
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 
}
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice .select2-chosen {
 cursor: default;
}
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice-focus {
 background: #d4d4d4;
}
 
.select2-search-choice-close {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0.75rem;
 height: 0.75rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: .25rem;
 top: .5rem;
 font-size: 1px;
 outline: none;
 background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") 50% 50% no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-search-choice-close {
 left: .25rem;
}
 
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice .select2-search-choice-close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice-focus .select2-search-choice-close {
 /*background-position: right -11px;*/
}
 
/* disabled styles */
.select2-container-multi.select2-container-disabled .select2-choices {
 background-color: #eee;
 background-image: none;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 cursor: default;
}
 
.select2-container-multi.select2-container-disabled .select2-choices .select2-search-choice {
 padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #eee;
}
 
.select2-container-multi.select2-container-disabled .select2-choices .select2-search-choice .select2-search-choice-close {
 display: none;
 background: none;
}
/* end multiselect */
 
 
.select2-result-selectable .select2-match,
.select2-result-unselectable .select2-match {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
 
.select2-offscreen, .select2-offscreen:focus {
 clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
 width: 1px !important;
 height: 1px !important;
 border: 0 !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 position: absolute !important;
 outline: 0 !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 top: 0px !important;
}
 
.select2-display-none {
 display: none;
}
 
.select2-measure-scrollbar {
 position: absolute;
 top: -10000px;
 left: -10000px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
}
/* Retina-ize icons */
 
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)  {
  .select2-search input, .select2-search-choice-close, .select2-container .select2-choice abbr, .select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow b {
   background-image: url('select2x2.png') !important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
   background-size: 60px 40px !important;
  }
  .select2-search input {
   background-position: 100% -21px !important;
  }
}

.tooltip{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="width: 175px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <ul class="select2-results">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">Hello</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">Greetings</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">Good-bye</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">Salutations</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
            <div class="select2-result-label">See ya!</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class='tooltip'></div>
```

Hope this will work for you...
If not ask for more.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution for my project

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted', function (e) {
                var data = $(this).data().data;
                var desc = "";
                if (data.description) {
                    desc = data.description;
                }
                if (desc != "") {
                    var t = $(this).tooltip({
                        title: desc,
                        placement: ($(window).width() < 1368 ? "bottom" : "right")
                    }).tooltip('show');
                }
            });
            $('body').on('mouseleave', '.select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted', function (e) {
                $(".select2-results__option").tooltip('destroy');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/8odneso7/2/ this also work fine and looks good, here is the code I found there:

HTML:

```
<select name="xxx" class="select-full" title="some_title">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="xxx2" class="select-full" title="another title">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="tip-normal" title="this one works">hover me</a>
```

JS (jQuery 3.4):

```
$('.tip-normal').tooltip({
    placement: "auto",
    html: true
});

$(".select-full").select2({
    width: "100%",
});

console.log($(".select2-container").length)
$(".select2-container").tooltip({
    title: function() {
        return $(this).prev().attr("title");
    },
    placement: "auto",
    //container: 'body'
});
```